# Java Nested JPanel with checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, nested-if

I am working on a menu ordering form. The program runs until the end where I have my last "if statement" that is to create a new Panel with check box options, that is then to open up to perform new work (display message or continue order details).

My first problem is that my check boxes are not being added to the new panel. I tried wrapping it in a new FlowLayout but only the header is showing.

I'm new to Java, only been programming a few months. This is a nested if-else statement. Not sure what to do. Here is the end part of the code. Any help pointing out my probably obvious mistakes would be appreciated. I want to learn.

This is inside the `actionPerformed` method of my `ClickAction`:

```
if (event.getSource()== order) {
    deliveryPanel = new JPanel();
    deliveryPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    headerLabel.setText("This Order will be for:");
    JCheckBox dv = new JCheckBox("Delivery"); 
    JCheckBox pu = new JCheckBox("Pick Up");
    deliveryPanel.add(dv);
    deliveryPanel.add(pu);

    CheckBoxHandler checkHandler = new CheckBoxHandler();

    pu.addItemListener(checkHandler); 
    dv.addItemListener(checkHandler);


    /*Options for delivery choice*/
    if (JCheckBox == pu) {
        System.out.println("Your Order"+ orderOutput+ "for" +name+ "will be ready for pickup");
    }
    else if (JCheckBox == dv){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please Enter your Delivery Address");  //input address

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"**Order Details**"+"\n"+"Name: "+name+"\n"+"Address: "+
            address+"\n"+"Order: "+orderOutput+"\n");
    }

    nameOutputMsg = "Welcome " + name + ".\n";
    greetingOutputMsg = "\nThank you for visiting Famous Favorite's Subs!" + "\n";

    //create output string
    outputMsg = nameOutputMsg
                + "**Order Details**"
                + "\nOrder: " + orderOutput
                + "\nQuantity : " + quantity
                + "\nDelivery Address: " + address
                + greetingOutputMsg;


    /*
     * output the order information to a file. Finally,
     * you will read this file to display the order confirmation information.
     */
    FileWriter fw = null; 
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(new File("output.txt"));
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be accessed/Created. ");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        fw.write(outputMsg);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be written.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        fw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be saved. ");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Scanner fileScanner = null;
    try {
        fileScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("output.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File could not be read or file not exists. ");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String fileText="";

    while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        fileText += fileScanner.nextLine()+"\n";
    }
    fileScanner.close();
    // display output message
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fileText);
    System.exit(0);


}

if (event.getSource() == exit) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for your Business.", "Goodbye", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
     System.exit(1); // terminate application
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile because of statements like `if (JCheckBox == pu)` and `else if (JCheckBox == dv)`.  You can't say is a class name equal to an object.  I'm sure what your intention was here or else I would suggest a fix.

Comment: "The program runs until the end where..."  What do you mean by this?  Do you get an exception?  If so, what's the stacktrace?  What line number does it point to?

Comment: I edited your question to make the code more readable.   I did the best I could, but there appeared to be some lacking matching opening parantheses. I made a guess that this was all inside the `actionPerformed` method of your `ClickAction`.  Was I right?

Comment: Really we need more code to give context.  What is `order`, `exit`, and several others?  Also you mentioned trying to use a `FlowLayout`, but that code is nowhere in the sample code.

Comment: I hope my suggestions help you improve the question so that we can better help you.  Please review [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When I said "opening parentheses" in my 3rd comment, I meant "opening brackets".  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are not displaying your deliveryPanel, you are just creating it. You need to add it to a frame in order for it to become visible.

If you want it to show up as a popup and not in the main window, you can add your deliveryPanel to a JOptionPane that shows up once the "order" event is pressed.

For example:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,deliveryPanel,"Order",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: I don't think the question, as of this writing, has enough context for you to make this assumption.

Comment: I am not sure if it was deleted or not but I believe a comment or post initially said that she did not want it to appear in the main window.

Comment: I think the post your are referring to is a deleted answer.  However, I still don't think we can necessarily assume from the code sample that she gave us that the `deliveryPanel` is never added, as `deliveryPanel` _appears_ to be a member variable.  Ah, but that is _my_ assumption there.  :-)  I could be wrong on both accounts.  The thing is, I think we just cannot know without out more code.